# Aproximation of indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

As I am not a math student, the following Notation might be wrong;

To aproximate an indefinite integral (without taylorseries), I thougt about using partial integrating a function again and again:
[here are my calculation][1]

My two questions are; how is this aproximation named and does it have any aplications as the Tayloraproximation converges mostly much faster.

Thank you for taking your time, to read my question.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oZNs.jpg

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.